# Determinant of $I+aa^T+bb^T$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given vectors $a$ and $b$, is there any good formula to find an equivalent form for

$$\det(I+aa^T+bb^T)$$

similar to the Sylvester’s determinant identity of $\det(I+aa^T)=1+a^Ta$?

Answer (score 7):

The [Weinstein–Aronszajn identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) states that $\det(I_m+AB) = \det(I_n+BA)$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix.

If we apply this formula for $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = A^T = \begin{bmatrix}a^T \\ b^T\end{bmatrix}$, then we have $$\det(I+aa^T+bb^T) = \det(I+AB) = \det(I_2+BA) = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}a^Ta+1 & a^Tb \\ b^Ta & b^Tb+1\end{bmatrix}\right) = (a^Ta+1)(b^Tb+1)-(a^Tb)(b^Ta) = (\|a\|_2^2+1)(\|b\|_2^2+1)-\langle a,b\rangle^2$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $$ A= \begin{pmatrix} & \\ a & b \\ & \end{pmatrix} $$
Then $I+aa^T+bb^T = I+AA^T$ and, according to the [Weinstein–Aronszajn identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),
$$
\det(I+AA^T) = \det(I_2 +A^T A)
=\det\begin{pmatrix} 1+a^Ta & a^T b \\   b^T a & 1+b^T b \end{pmatrix}
\\
= (1+a^Ta)(1+b^T b) - (a^T b)^2
$$